# how limit getting changes for a user in TFS?

Tags: tfs, permissions

I want to limit a user in `TFS`.I want he get all of changes in my repository except  changes of a special user.how can i do it?

thanks

Comment: That's not how source control works.

Comment: I only want to know can i do it in tfs? And a tutorial for learning it @DanielMann

Comment: No, you can't. Like I said, that's not how source control works. You could use branches to segregate work from other users, but you can't selectively ignore one person's changes.

Comment: Hi zohreh, it's not able to do this. Just as Daniel point out in the comment, that's not how source control works. Do you still have any other concern on this? Checking to see if the information provided was helpful. If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for marking it as an answer which will also helps others in the community.

Answer (score 0):

It's not able to do this in TFS.

We could use permissions to limit access to particular files/folders or branches. However, we could not limit access to someone's changes.

As you know, we store source control changes as changeset or commit.

When you check in your changes, they are stored on the server as a changeset. Changesets contain the history of each item in version control.

**You can view a changeset to see what the exact file changes were**, discover the owner's comments, find linked work items, and see if any policy warnings were triggered.

In other words, we are not able to mange permission for a special changeset. For example it's not able to forbid a user to see changeset 100, but be able to see changeset 99, changeset 101.

It's also not able to block user which make him unable to view the revision history or get a specific version of a file/folder.